# Шифр цезаря с ключевым словом и криптоаналитическая атака

Tags: python, безопасность, шифрование

есть код который правильно шифрует слово по цезарю с ключевым словом но и надо сделать для дешифровку ,сделал с помощью криптоаналитической атаки,вроде всё реализовал правильно и взял у друга пример,у него все работает а у меня проблема с размерностью не могу понять почему

IndexError: list index out of range в 63 строке ошибка
LetterSwap = []

```
for i in range(len(EngAlphabet)):
    LetterSwap.append([EngAlphabet[i][0], CryptAlphabet[i][0]])
```

в этом цикле

```
from random import *
import string

Alphalist = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
file = open('текст для теса.txt', 'r')
startMessage = file.read().upper()
startMessage = startMessage.translate(str.maketrans(' ', ' ', string.punctuation))  # избавились от знаков препинания
print("Текст для зашифровки:", startMessage)
numberkey = int(input('Отступ: '))
key=[Alphalist[randint(0,len(Alphalist))-1]for i in range(1,len(Alphalist))]
key=set(key)
key=''.join(list(key))
print('Ключевое слово:',key)


def remove(alpha, string):
    for symbol in string:
        if symbol not in [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)] \
        or string.count(symbol) > 1: string.remove(symbol)
        if symbol in alpha: alpha.remove(symbol)
    return alpha, string


def insert(alpha_string):
    for index, symbol in enumerate(alpha_string[1]):
        alpha_string[0].insert((numberkey + index) % 26, symbol)
    return alpha_string[0]


def encryptDecrypt( message, keyy,final=""):
    alpha = insert(remove(Alphalist, key))
    print(alpha)
    for symbol in message:
            final += alpha[(alpha.index(symbol) + keyy) % 26]
    return final
def encryptDecrypt1( message, keyy,final1=""):
    alpha = insert(remove(Alphalist, key))
    print(alpha)
    for symbol in message:
            final1 += alpha[(alpha.index(symbol) - keyy) % 26]
    return final1


message = encryptDecrypt( startMessage, numberkey)

print("Final", message)
EngAlphabet = [[' ', 0.185], ['e', 0.097], ['t', 0.076], ['a', 0.064], ['o', 0.062], ['n', 0.057], ['i', 0.056],
               ['s', 0.052], ['r', 0.047], ['h', 0.04], ['l', 0.031], ['d', 0.028], ['c', 0.025], ['u', 0.018],
               ['p', 0.018], ['f', 0.018], ['m', 0.017], ['w', 0.016], ['y', 0.015], ['b', 0.013], ['g', 0.013],
               ['v', 0.007], ['k', 0.0039], ['q', 0.002], ['x', 0.002], ['j', 0.001], ['z', 0.001]]

CryptAlphabet = []
for i in set(''.join(list(message))):
    CryptAlphabet.append([i, message.count(i) / len(message)])

for i in range(len(CryptAlphabet) - 1):
    for j in range(len(CryptAlphabet) - i - 1):
        if CryptAlphabet[j][1] < CryptAlphabet[j + 1][1]:
            CryptAlphabet[j], CryptAlphabet[j + 1] = CryptAlphabet[j + 1], CryptAlphabet[j]

LetterSwap = []
for i in range(len(EngAlphabet)):
    LetterSwap.append([EngAlphabet[i][0], CryptAlphabet[i][0]])

Run = True
while Run:
    EncryptWord = ""
    for letter in message:
        for i in LetterSwap:
            if letter == i[1]:
                EncryptWord += i[0]
                break

    print('расшифрованный текст:', EncryptWord)
```

Answer (score 0):

В списке  длиной `i` отсутствует элемент `[i]`. Замените на `EngAlphabet[i-1]` и `CryptAlphabet[i-1]`. А ещё лучше используйте словарь, а не список.

Comment: Спасибо а это где именно,что то не могу понять

Comment: В строке 63. И в других строках

Comment: Хмм,что то не получается

Comment: Что не получается? Заменить?

Comment: Да,не совсем понятно в каких местах,поменял в 63 строке такая же ошибка

Comment: Такая же ошибка в той же строке? Какова длина CryptAlphabet?

Comment: Да,такая же ошибка ,длина не указана

Comment: Ну так надо посмотреть и вывести, чтобы знать. И сравнить с длиной EngAlphabet.

Comment: Все понял в чем проблема я не учитывал в EngAlph пробел ,в итоге у меня 26 там длина а в другом 27

Comment: А это значит на входе должно быть слово с пробелом,но он уже ругается на шифровку,эх

Comment: А ой всё ошибся в EngAlph нормально всё а вот в crypt 4 длина,ибо если слово ALOHA и он его шифрует он берет 4 буквы,что как и есть ,в итоге как то в этом ошибка